# Update Custom Field Type Field by REST API SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, rest, metadata, custom-field-types, updatelistitems

I have a REST api to update the different fields of Item in the list

```
$.ajax({  
    url: projectSiteURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items(10)",  
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",  
    data: JSON.stringify  
    ({  
        '__metadata':  
        {  
            'type': 'SP.Data.MyListListItem' 
        },  
        'DocDescription': "test",
        'CustomStatus': "Specific value here in custom field type format"  
    }),  
    headers:  
    {  
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest":  $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "IF-MATCH": "*" ,
        "X-Http-Method": "MERGE" 
    },  
    success: function(data, status, xhr)  
    {  
        console.log(status);  
    },  
    error: function(xhr, status, error)  
    {  
        console.log(error); 
    }  
});
```

When I execute above code, it gives me error:

> "The property 'CustomStatus' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.MyListListItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."

I have that field on the list of type custom field type which I created by code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms415141(v=office.14).aspx).

I have also checked when I get item with REST Api, even when I do have value in that field, I don't get that field value in a result. Can someone tell me please what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far found nothing for the answer.

Seems **it is not possible** with the REST API.

But if someone can correct me here, please add answer.